# how to convert HTML modal conent to pdf with inline css in angular 7?

Tags: canvas, angular7, clj-pdf

I am trying to convert html modal content to pdf.I also tried to use jsPDF and its working but my custom css is not applied in the pdf section.i have to apply my custom css to pdf section.

**I tried below solution**

```js
  download(){
     var data = document.getElementById('download_modal_content');  //Id of the table
      html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {  
        // Few necessary setting options  
        let imgWidth = 208;   
        let pageHeight = 295;    
        let imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;  
        let heightLeft = imgHeight;  

        const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')  
        let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF  
        let position = 0;  
        pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)  
        pdf.save('download.pdf');
      });  
  }
```

tell me anyone how to apply my custom css to pdf section?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using html2pdf.js lib (https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2pdf.js)
It englobe html2canvas and jspdf.